# .main-question-link:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

Tags: feature-request, design

Please add an underline to the main question link/title on hover. I use it to refresh a question and it's not as clearly clickable without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the onhover underline for the question title. It will be in the next deployment.