# Hover over icons behavior

Tags: feature-request, design

Since this SE site is all about user experience, wouldn't it be a good idea to set the example for other SE sites and add hover animations to the icons as discussed [in this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6573/3612) and [its answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/hover-over-icon/6582#6582)?

I'm talking about the upvote/downvote/fav and mark as answer icons in particular, but as [this question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/315/3612) on meta here indicates I would try to provide a [consistent GUI](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/6576/3612) across the entire site.

Comment: Which icons are you referring to? The main ones: Up/Down votes, Fav star, and Answer?

Comment: @Jin: Yup, updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @Jin - see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/accept-answer-checkmark-could-still-be-clearer